# file_get_contents return html code why

Tags: php, yii, file-get-contents

I have this url : http://localhost/Test/ in my Test it is a folder content csv files so i used this function but the result it always contents html code i don't understand why.

```
$auth = base64_encode('test:test');
$aContext = array(
  'http' => array(
    'proxy'           => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:80',
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    'header'          => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth",
  ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$sFile = file_get_contents("http://localhost/Test/", false, $cxContext);
echo $sFile;
```

Comment: You are getting contents of an URL, not of a file. To do this, you have to pass to `file_get_contents` the local path of desired file.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP server tries to get `index.php` to every directory you access, if you want to list the `CSV` files, you need to create an `index.php` that list the files.

In your **index.php**:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($csvFile = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($csvFile != "." && $csvFile != "..") {

            echo "$csvFile\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

If you want just a file, put the direct path in `file_get_contents`.

```
$sFile = file_get_contents("http://localhost/Test/file.csv", False, $cxContext);
```